# Filter last slash of URL and return the last character

Tags: javascript

I can get the last character of the last part of the URL by using the split method and pop method such as
`.split("/").pop()` .

But usually, there is a slash at the end of the URL like so: https://exmaple.com/123/456/

It will return empty because there is simply nothing after the last slash.

How do I get the number '6' that is in the last part of the URL in the best and easy way?

Comment: What about `str.replaceAll('/', '').slice(-1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just remove the slashes, and return the last character no matter what it is.

Here's a quick example:

```js
const getLastChar = (str) =>
  str.replaceAll('/', '').slice(-1);
  
// Example #1 - Trailing slash
console.log(getLastChar('https://exmaple.com/123/456/'));

// Example #2 - No trailing slash
console.log(getLastChar('https://exmaple.com/123/456'));
```

If it's based on user input, don't forget to also check that the string is present / defined too :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove the last "/" Like this:

```
let str =  "https://example.com/abc/123/";

//if the str has a "/" at the end, remove it
if (str.endsWith("/")) {
    str = str.slice(0, -1);
}

// str =  "https://example.com/abc/123"
console.log(str);
```